# get application name from pid

Tags: linux, command-line, process

I am trying to get application name by typing a command but it seems like there is no command to get application name from process id.
We can only get process name from using process id in command.
The command is `ps -p <process id> o comm=` , which return process name.
I want to get application name by using of process id so my query is that:
which command I can use to get application name using the process id in Linux?

Comment: which linux are you using ?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `/proc` on recent Linux:

```
ls -l /proc/[PID]/exe  
#or
readlink /proc/[PID]/exe
```

This file should be a link to the executable use by this PID.

Comment: This is working for me on CentOS. I prefer readlink since it outputs only the executable. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinLemaire it's a matter of taste. It more exploitable I have to agree. You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

On a platform with a standard `procfs` with procfs-2 support, you get the result via:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/path/a.out
```

The file a.out is a symlink to the absolute path of the binary.